# High CPU usage and no recharge upon Android phone USB-C connection

Tags: windows-10, usb, android

I wanted to charge my phone/hotspot's battery, `Google Pixel 5`. My bright idea was to connect it to my `Dell 7790` laptop using the laptop's embedded USB-C port, using the same both-sided<sup>1</sup> cable (Amazon Basics) used to charge the battery on 220V. Namely, I was just too lazy to stand up and go to the nearest 220V outlet.

Strange thing happened: Windows became unstable, in the sese that mouse pointer was not very responsive and even writing text. CPU usage, once I was finally able to open Task Manager, was high by System, but really not 100%.

I disconnected my phone and normality came back. I reconnected the phone and noticed it didn't start charging.

Android developer tools are enable, but USB debugging is not. Hotspot is running over Wifi, not USB (there is a USB tethering option, I haven't enabled it).

Any idea?

[1] USB-C male to USB-C male

Comment: It can happen that when you connect two devices via USB-C the "charge direction" the devices negotiate is unexpected, e.g. that your phone charges your notebook and not the other way around. Is it possible that this happened in your case?

Comment: @Robert great idea, but it's disabled

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ Are you 100% it's a male to male cable, as USB-C cables are usually female to female, with the male ports being on the device? Does the same occur with another USB-C cable?

Comment: @JW0914 USB-C plugs are always male: `Two kinds (genders) of connectors exist, female (receptacle) and male (plug).` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Connectors

Comment: @Robert Ah, I thought the receptacle protrusion was the male that fits inside the female portion of the male plug _(e.g. a lighting cable end with the protrusion would be male)_